# What have the arguments on a callback function in Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using draggable from jquery UI,
I want to know what does UI argument has, because I want to know the handle position calling the stop() callback function.

Then I want to set an value to move the draggable to a specific position. Knowing that, how can I set the value, (like slider). http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-value

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to say it, but RTFD:

> All callbacks (start, stop, drag) receive two arguments: The original browser event and a prepared ui object, view below for a documentation of this object (if you name your second argument 'ui'):
>
> - **ui.helper** - the jQuery object representing the helper that's being dragged
> - **ui.position** - current position of the helper as { top, left } object, relative to the offset element
> - **ui.offset** - current absolute position of the helper as { top, left } object, relative to page

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: RTFD... how have I never seen this before! Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

[Options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#options)
and 
[Events](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events)
read up

Comment: is there anything about event function arguments? I think not, thanks anyway